# phpThumb PDF thumbnail

Tags: php, pdf-generation, imagemagick, ghostscript, phpthumb

I am using phpThumb to create thumbnails of PDFs uploaded to my site.

This is working for some PDFs but others produce an error that states imagemagick and or ghostscript are unavailable.

These should be available as phpThumb is using these for the working PDF thumbnails.

One thing that I have noticed is that it tends to be PDFs that are generated on a Mac that are causing the problem. Does anybody know of a fix to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who is finding this question through searching I have managed to fix this after emailing Silisoftware who make phpThumb.

Certain PDFs were causing a problem with ghostscript, I have solved this by manually lowering the DPI setting for PDF thumbnails. I found that mine crashes over 117dpi.

You can set the dpi using the following parameter -

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=/test.pdf&dpi=117
```

Hope this helps someone.